# C# WPF Issues With Balloon Tip On Click Repeating Actions

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I'm probably missing the obvious and please bear with me as I am learning as I go with this build, but I have a problem with a WPF application that uses balloon tips to notify the users of events and they then click the balloon tip to open a window to give them more information. This works fine but we need to multithread the balloon tips so more than one will show at a time, and this is when we get into an issue.

The first balloon tip is shown and when clicking on it we get the window opening properly, close the window and everything works great. When the second balloon tip shows and is clicked it generates 2 new windows, the third generates 3 and so on.

For simplicity the 2 events we are testing against are timers set by objects. I will run through the whole process as I am unsure as to where our issue sits.

The Objects are defined as follows :-

```
public class Item
    {
        public string ItemID { get; set; }
        public string ItemName { get; set; }
        public string ItemText { get; set; }
        public string ConfigValue { get; set; }
    }
```

We have 2 items set which we add to a list called repeatItems:-

```
Item1 (ItemID = "1", ItemName = "Item1", ItemText = "Test text for item1", ConfigValue = "1")
Item2 (ItemID = "2", ItemName = "Item2", ItemText = "Test text for item2", ConfigValue = "2")
```

We then use a task factory to allow us to setup 2 separate timers :-

```
//Create Task Factory to handle Repeat Items
var repTaskFactory = new TaskFactory();

//Create Thread for Repeat Items
foreach (Item item in repeatItems)
{
    repTaskFactory.StartNew(() => RepItem(item));
}
```

The RepItem function is defined as is follows :-

```
//Function to handle Repeat Items
        public async void RepItem(Item item)
        {
            //Create a new custom timer
            var repTimer = new CustomTimer();

            //assign Item details to the timer
            repTimer.item = item;

            //create and set the timer time value as confiog value is in Minutes
            var mil = Int32.Parse(nudge.ConfigValue) * 60 * 1000;
            repTimer.Interval = mil;

            //set the response for the timer ending
            repTimer.Elapsed += ItemAction;

            //cause timer to autorepeat
            repTimer.AutoReset = true;

            //Start the timer
            repTimer.Enabled = true;
        }
```

The CustomTimer called is set follows to allow it to carry additional information for later calls :-

```
class CustomTimer : System.Timers.Timer
    {
        public Item item;
    }
```

The action function is :-

```
public void ItemAction(Object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            //Create ability to multi thread allowing multiple balloon tips to be displayed
            var balloonTaskFactory = new TaskFactory();
            
            //Get details from the sending time
            CustomTimer timer = (CustomTimer)source;

            //Get Item from the timer type
            Item item = new Item();
            item = timer.item;

            //Create new thread and show ballon tip
            balloonTaskFactory.StartNew(() => CreateItemBalloonTip(item));         
        }
```

And finally we create and show the balloon tip :-

```
public void CreateItemBalloonTip(Item item)
        {
            //Set details of Balloon Tip
            m_notifyIcon.BalloonTipText = item.ItemText;
            m_notifyIcon.BalloonTipTitle = item.ItemName;
            m_notifyIcon.BalloonTipClicked += new EventHandler(ItemBalloonTipClicked);

            m_notifyIcon.ShowBalloonTip(2000);
        }
```

ItemBalloonTipClicked is fairly simple in that it opens a new window and passes the item.ItemName to it :-

```
public void ItemBalloonTipClicked(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            NotifyIcon cust = (NotifyIcon)sender;

            string item = cust.BalloonTipTitle;
            Window1 win2 = new Window1(item);
            win2.Show();
        }
```

Somewhere I am guessing the listener for BalloonTipClicked is not closing down and is firing over and over? How do I handle this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to unregister the event handler to the `BalloonTipClicked` event in the click event handler:

```
public void ItemBalloonTipClicked(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    NotifyIcon cust = (NotifyIcon)sender;
    cust.BalloonTipClicked -= ItemBalloonTipClicked; // <--

    string item = cust.BalloonTipTitle;
    Window1 win2 = new Window1(item);
    win2.Show();
}
```

Comment: That has worked perfectly, thanks. I knew I was missing something simple :)